# Excel Macro Error - "User Defined Type Not Defined" - References Grayed out

Tags: vba, excel

So I created this code (probably don't even have to show it- but just in case!), have not been able to test it as I get "User defined type not defined" on the first line. I saw that I should set the reference in Tools>References but
the option is grayed out....

```
Sub UploadDistributors()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB-Removed for security-Network Library=DBMSSOCN"

cnn.Open strConn 

Dim k
k = 0

   For i = 1 To 352

   sSQL = "INSERT INTO DistributorsNP (CompanyName, address, city, state, zip, phone,    tollfree) VALUES ("

    'CompanyName
    sSQL = sSQL & Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value & ","
    'address
    sSQL = sSQL & Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value & ","
    'city
    sSQL = sSQL & Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value & ","
    'state
    sSQL = sSQL & Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value & ","
    'zip
    sSQL = sSQL & Sheet1.Range("F" & i).Value & ","
    'phone
    sSQL = sSQL & Sheet1.Range("G" & i).Value & ","
    'tollfree
    sSQL = sSQL & Sheet1.Range("H" & i).Value & ","



sSQL = sSQL & ")"
rs.Open sSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

rs.Close

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: as @MattCrum alluded to below. Make sure you are out of debug mode in the VBE. (Press the blue square in the menu bar).Then `Tools>Reference` will become available for you to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing you've pressed stop in the editor and are no longer in break mode...?

Comment: You were right, I pressed stop and then was able to see References. Problem now is I still get the error even though I added the Reference "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"

Comment: Try adding Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library